# How to compare K2 blackpearl .sodx files with latest TFS version

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs, k2, k2-blackpearl

I am maintaining an older K2 blackpearl system for a customer. The development environment is a virtual machine running Windows Server 2008R2 Datacenter with K2 blackpearl 4.6.6 and Visual Studio Professional 2012. The  development environment is connected through VPN to the customers Team Foundation Server.

The previous developer who handed over the project to me, apparently made some changes, which I do not know the extent of. And this person is not available in the company anymore. On the Visual Studio Team Explorer I have a couple of pending changes in some .sodx files and a .dll file like shown here.

[image]

However I am not able to see, which changes were made. If I rightclick and choose "Compare with Latest Version", I just see a lot of unreadable XML code (.sodx). This doesn't tell me anything useful.

So my question is. Are there a way of finding out, which changes were made to these files?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If a SODX file is an XML file and it shows you a diff of XML, that sounds like correct behavior. What exactly are you expecting?

Comment: @DanielMann Yes I can see that the files have been changed. But what I want to see is WHAT has been changed in the files. When comparing the XML (SODX) files all I see is a lot of unuseful keys and such generated by K2. I want to find out what the previous developer changed in the files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Comparing files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/compare-files)  is the right way to show the difference of two version files in TFS source contol.

Since you have see the files have been changed, just the changed is unuseful  or  meaningless to you. This is not related to TFS area.

If you are worrying about the changes will influence your code or environment, you could simply [roll back the changesets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/roll-back-changesets)  after you checked in the pending changes. If you undo the pending changes, these will just disappear and not able to recover. So suggest you to check in the pending changes.  Another way is  connecting to the  previous developer and directly get changed things from him. After all, this is also belongs to your working transition.

Comment: Thanks for your opinion @Patrick-MSFT. This is also what I chose to do. To prevent any loss of work, I checked in the pending changes. If we then are having issues on a later point, we can roll back again.